# Add a Number in Front of the String - PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc

The question is very basic, but your input is greatly appreciated.

I basically need to add '1' in front of the existing value of the variable (no space as delimiter). Here is my best attempt so far:

```
proc sql;
   create table as select * from connection to oracle
      (
      select catx('','1',A.Var_Name) AS "#New_Var" from table_name;
      )
quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get what you want.  If you have a column in Oracle and want to concatenate a value, you can use:

```
proc sql;
    select '1' || a.Var_Name
    from table_name;
quit;
```

Comment: This is what I just did, and then I saw your answer. Thanks a lot for a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

SAS does not have a concept of "empty string", so

```
select catx('','1',A.Var_Name) AS "#New_Var" from table_name;
```

Is identical to

```
select catx(' ','1',A.Var_Name) AS "#New_Var" from table_name;
```

`CATS` however would remove spaces for you; or `CATT` if you only want to remove trailing spaces.

```
select cats('1',A.Var_Name) AS New_Var from table_name;
```

If you need anything more complicated than that (such as `A.Var_Name` has trailing spaces that you want to preserve) then you would need to do the work yourself to trim off spaces and then concatenate using the concatenation operator, like Gordon mentions.

Also note that if you're doing this in `SAS`, and not pass-through, you want to use the above syntax for the column name, not `"#` style.